# Autowired object is null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot.class);

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    public CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a, FilterInvocation fi) {
        super(a, fi);
    }

    public boolean isOwner(Integer id) {
        String username = ((UserDetails) getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        User user = new User();
        if (userService == null) {
            logger.debug("USER SERVICE NULL");
        }
        try {
            user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug("NULL");
        }
        return id == user.getId();
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at waterfall.model.User.getId(User.java:62)
    at waterfall.config.CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot.isOwner(CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot.java:37)
```

In other classes, like **controller**, it works perfectly fine but in the **class** above userService is null. I have no clue why it is null. What can cause my issue?

Comment: What is line 37 mentioned in the exception's stacktrace?

Comment: Also please share some more of your code.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex line 37 is `return id == user.getId();`

Comment: Show the code at `User.java:62`, that's where the NPE comes from.

Comment: Also lose the catch clause catching the NPE.

Comment: @dunni The idea why NPE comes from is just because `user = userService.findByUsername(username)` returns null and therefore it can't take id from user and causes NPE

Comment: See [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 0):

Autowired only works in spring components like `Service`, `Controller` or Component.
You could solve your issue by adding `@Component` and scanning the given path. However you should look up the consequences of this.

Comment: After adding `@Component` annotation it threw the following exceptions: 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.Authentication' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}` 
and
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customWebSecurityExpressionRoot' defined in file `

Comment: Spring is trying to instanciate the CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot using the constructor you provided, but can't guess how to create your constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I could find only two possibilities where the autowiring didn't work :

1) Your CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot hasn't been created by Spring (you instanciated it by yourself ?).

2) Your CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot is final.

Comment: Why would `final` would not allow for proper autowiring? Having a `final` service is perfectly valid for Spring and does not impeded with dependency injection.

Comment: Some classes need to be proxyied by Spring (it is the case for classes with @Transactional annotation for exemple). If the class is not final, Spring can't do so, and the autowiring will fail.